# What is the different between 3 tap nitro and perfect nitro

Tags: asphalt-8

I see the top speed is the same after aceleration is over, so beside the sound and the smoke what is the difference?

I think perfect nitro take longer because you have to wait, and in some videos where try to show best route they use 3 tap instead of perfect nitro. So want to be sure what is better. Or maybe there are cases where one is better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in speed boosting power of both....

The difference is that perfect nitro is activated when u tap nitro second time (when nitro meter is in red area)..

Perfect nitro has a benefit over 3 tap nitro that it lasts longer I.e it gives boost for a longer time than 3tap using the same amount of your nitro fuel...